# How to connect Devise User to ProfilesController Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Before I begin, let me say that I have two different devise user models.

I began removing the unnecessary methods from the scaffold_controller, because devise handles certain actions.

I'm trying to route to the current_user profile page, but I get an error every time I try to add the link in my navbar <%= 'My Profile', current_user %> doesn't work in this case. I plan to setup the associations as soon as I finish hooking up these controllers.

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /profiles
  # GET /profiles.json
  def index
    @profiles = Profile.all
  end

  # GET /profiles/1
  # GET /profiles/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {render :json => @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /profiles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /profiles/1
  # DELETE /profiles/1.json
  def destroy
    @profile.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to profiles_url, notice: 'Profile was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_profile
      @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def profile_params
      params[:profile]
    end
end
 profiles GET    /profiles(.:format)                          profiles#index
                              POST   /profiles(.:format)                          profiles#create
                  new_profile GET    /profiles/new(.:format)                      profiles#new
                 edit_profile GET    /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)                 profiles#edit
                      profile GET    /profiles/:id(.:format)                      profiles#show
                              PATCH  /profiles/:id(.:format)                      profiles#update
                              PUT    /profiles/:id(.:format)                      profiles#update
                              DELETE /profiles/:id(.:format)                      profiles#destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (such as bad thing to do), that you have already created the profile while creating the user ( since there is no create action in the controller ) and that a profile belongs_to a user, then this should work:

```
<%= link_to "My Profile", current_user.profile %>
```

Generally, I would get my associations set up properly *before* I even look at the controllers.

Comment: I'll try this solution shortly, and report back to you.

Comment: What I'll do is erase the profile controller and add a show action to the user controller. Hopefully, I'll be able to work from that angle. This seems to be an overly complicated method.